# Synchronization in one thread c++ program

Tags: c++, race-condition

I have a program with a main loop receiving messages.
One of these messages is `registersReady`. I want to read the register state for the first time. The result will be provided as an event through the main loop and stored in a global variable.
After `registersReady` message, I message `registersChanged` can be received. I want to store result in a global variable as well.

In a pseudocode, it's something like this:

```
    Data data;
    while (true){
        message = recv();
        switch (message){
        case registersReady:
            readInitialRegistersState();
        case readInitialRegisterStateFinished:
            data = message.data;
        case registersChanged:
            data = message.data;
    }
```

The problem can occur if `registersChanged` occurs before `readInitialRegisterStateFinished`.

How to avoid data race in such case? Are there any patterns? I can't use mechanisms like mutexes and conditional variables. This is one thread program I can receive messages only through main receiving loop.

Br.
Albus

I was trying to find patterns on how to avoid races in such case but I couldn't find them.

I will be grateful for help.

Comment: There is no data race. Data races can only occur between multiple threads or between one thread and a signal handler (analogously interrupt handler) on it. You don't seem to have any of that. All I see you need is another `bool` variable to indicate to you whether `readInitialRegisterStateFinished` has already been received to then act accordingly.

Comment: I'm afraid bool variable will not help in the scenario below.

registersReady(t1) <--
readInitReg(t2)  -->
hereRegistersWereRead (t3) --
hereRegistersWereSamplednd change was detected(t4) --
stateRegChangedCallback (t5) <--
readInitRegCallback (t6) -->
                              
If events occurs in this order additional bool variable will not help.
I will lose information about changed state because it will overwritten with intial value of registersReady

Comment: OK, then you need to store that information somewhere else. The point is that none of this has anything to do with synchronization or data races. You just have to keep track of your state.

Comment: Is the whole program written by you? Including the part you are communicating with? Does it involve hardware access? (You are talking about registers.) Is the problem from the view of your message loop that you cannot read the state anymore, because it was already overwritten elsewhere, before you had the chance to read; or is the problem that you yourself are overwriting in the message loop, because you store in the same variable? In the second case you need a different data structure for storing. Either with two slots or e.g. a queue or ring buffer.

Comment: Or you have to prevent or delay the program from continuing, until the data is received.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a flag *registers_ready* and set it when you done with initial registration. And don't forget to end each case section with break:

```
bool registers_ready=false;

Data data;
while (true){
    message = recv();
    switch (message){
    case registersReady:
        readInitialRegistersState();
        break;
    case readInitialRegisterStateFinished:
        data = message.data;
        registers_ready=true;
        break;
    case registersChanged:
        if (registers_ready) {
            data = message.data;
        }
        break;
}
```

Depending on your data variable format and value ranges, you could use it as a flag (in case it takes non-zero values, for example).

Answer (score 1):

Search for state machine pattern. It's not exactly your use case but the main idea is applicable. Your process can be in a number of states. For example: `None, Initializing, Running, Finished`. Then you carefully manage transition between the states. If some messages arrive before they are expected you can either discard or cache. Replay them when the process enters the right state.